# Concatenate Strings in the strings.xml file for Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Is possible to concatenate a String already existing in strings.xml with the current one.
That is: If I have

```
<string name="hello">hello</string>
```

and I want to create a new string with the format   `"Your android says "+hello`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I am afraid that is not possible in `strings.xml`.

What you can do is create the final string programmatically using [`getString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)):

```
String outStr = getString(R.string.your_android_says) + 
  " " + getString(R.string.hello);
```

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
String s = "Your android says" + getResources().getString(R.id.name);
```

What you could also do it like:

```
<string name="hello">%s hello</string>

String androidsays = "Your android says";
String s = getString(R.id.name, androidsays);
```

Comment: the latter is the way to do it

Comment: how if %s has more than 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

you can create any number of altered string , but bounded upto runTime memory only . you can't store persistently this new string like usually you do through `values/string.xml` .

example `String newString = "something" + getResources().getString(id);`

`sharedPreferences` in the way you can achieve this . store newly generated string into sharedpreferences and access later .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do so without having to add any Java/Kotlin code, you could use this small library I've created: https://github.com/LikeTheSalad/android-stem

It allows you to do something like this:

```
<string name="app_name">world</string>
<string name="welcome_message">hello ${app_name}</string>
```

And then the library does this at build time:

```
<!-- Auto generated during compilation -->
<string name="welcome_message">hello world</string>
```