# How can I nest string resource?

Tags: android, android-resources

This is what I want to do, in standard way.

```
<string name="foo">foo</string>
<string name="foo_bar">foo bar</string>
```

Can I rewrite like below?

```
<string name="foo">foo</string>
<string name="foo_bar">@string/foo bar</string>
```

I know this is not in schema, however, it is OK like below,

```
<string name="foo">foo</string>
<string name="altfoo">@string/foo</string>
```

Why!?

Comment: what you actully want to do???

Comment: Yes you can do as the last one

Comment: see if this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161256/android-reference-a-string-in-a-string-array-resource-with-xml

Comment: Sorry second example "foo_bar" should be `@string/foo bar`

Comment: I actually want second one.

Comment: The problem is that you can't concatenate an integer (`@string/foo` refers to an identifier) with a string, because the whole will then be interpreted as a string, so the identifier won't be handled.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
<string name="foo">foo</string>
<string name="foo_bar">@string/foo bar</string>
```

wrong coz there is no resource with the name foo bar

The above would be right if you had

```
<string name="foo bar">foo and bar</string>
<string name="foo_bar">@string/foo bar</string>
```

This

```
<string name="foo">foo</string>
<string name="altfoo">@string/foo</string>
```

is right coz there is a resource with name foo and you are referencing the same

You may want to check

[Concatenate Strings in the strings.xml file for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353929/concatenate-strings-in-the-strings-xml-file-for-android)

Comment: The link you point to actually says you can't do it like your answer... Have you really tried it?

Comment: @TactMayers what mistake are you pointing @?. You can try it and then inform

Comment: You can't write `<string name="altfoo">@string/foo</string>` and expect the string `altfoo` has the value `foo`. This will not work.

Comment: @TactMayers no it will work if you have `<string name="foo">foo</string>`. try it yourself

Comment: Alright... I misunderstood. If it's a direct reference it will work. But concatenation will not work.